Tensor product of a line bundle and its dual bundle
Let $L$ be a complex line bundle over an $m$-dimensional manifold $M$, and $L^*$ its dual line bundle. (That is: the fibers of $L^*$ are linear maps from the fibers of $L$ into C.)
How to show that $L \otimes L^*$ is a trivial line bundle?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

The line-bundle part is irrelevant. In general every endomorphism bundle is trivializable (hint: in the space of endomorphisms, there’s an obvious non-zero element).

@peek-a-boo The line bundle part is not irrelevant at all, and it is not true that endomorphism bundles in general are trivializable. In fact, as you basically give away in the hint, you always get a nonvanishing section, but that's obviously not enough to conclude that the bundle is trivial if $\dim L > 1$.

It seems like this question has never been asked in quite this form, but you can find almost everything you need to piece together an answer yourself from this answer and this question.

@BenSteffan omg yes, my bad. I’ve been working with principal bundles recently where a single section suffices, and I badly mixed up the situations. Thanks for the obvious correction.

There are some abstract argument with Chern class or $L\otimes L^*\simeq \text{End}(L)$. Here is a down-to-earth one:
It suffices to show $L\otimes L^*$ has a nonzero continuous section (since it's of dimension $1$). To do so, over any fibre $l$, pick $x\in l\setminus\{0\}$ and $x^*\in l^*$ such that $x^*(x)=1$. Now pick $x\otimes x^*\in l\otimes l^*$.
Note that $x\otimes x^*$ is independent of $x$: $(kx)^*(kx)=k(kx)^*(x) = 1, (kx)^*(x)=\frac{1}{k}$, $(kx)^*=\frac{1}{k}x^*$, hence $(kx)\otimes (kx)^*=(kx)\otimes \frac{1}{k}x^*=x\otimes x^*$. Or more straightforwardly, $l\otimes l^*\simeq \mathbb C$ by $x\otimes f\mapsto f(x)$, and $x\otimes x^*=x^*(x)=1$ doesn't depend on $x$. Therefore we already have a section, so we don't have to worry about gluing, but only continuity which is also trivial: for any trivilization $L|_U\simeq U\times \mathbb C$, we can certainly pick $x=(u, 1)$ for any $u\in U$, hence $u\mapsto x(u)\otimes x(u)^*$ is (locally) continuous.
So not only $L\otimes L^*$ is trivial but canonically trivial. In particular, there is a canonical isomorhpism between $L\otimes L^*$ and $L'\otimes L'^*$.
